# C++ non-type template template parameters, reference to *this

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, reference, non-type

I'm trying to improve my generic architecture, and I've decided that a system that uses this type of ambiguous context referencing would be ideal for my purposes. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the syntax to work. I don't even know if something like this is possible! I have slightly shiestier alternatives that accomplish mostly the same thing but this would be best:

```
class IContained
{
public:
    virtual int getInt() = 0;
};
typedef std::shared_ptr<IContained>IContainedPtr;

template<template<class RefType, RefType& itsRef> class ContainedType>
class TestClass
{
    TestClass() :
        myContained(new ContainedType < TestClass, *this>())
    {

    }

    int getContextInt()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    IContainedPtr myContained;
};

template<class RefType, RefType& itsRef>
class Contained:
    virtual public IContained
{

    int getInt()
    {
        return itsRef.getContextInt();
    }
};

TEST(POTATO, PARTY)
{
    TestClass<Contained> myTest();

    int thing = myTest.myContained->getInt();

    EXPECT_EQ(thing, 3);
}
```

Comment: Might be better to use words or even better class diagram to explain what you are trying to accomplish. Your code isn't even near compiling so it's hard to infer the question based on the code alone.

Comment: Could you please try to narrow down, what would you like to be helped with? "Get this working for me" is a bit too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I thought someone might recognize the problem by sight. Turns out someone did, thankfully. I included my GTest stuff just so you could see how I would want to implement the classes. It would take a while to explain how this fits in context...

Anyway thanks for your time, guys. I know what's wrong with it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what do you want to implement but I can explain why you are not able to use

```
*this
```

as template argument. Templates provide you with compile-time polymorphism. It means that all templates arguments should be known at compile time.

```
this
```

is a class instance variable, is an address of class instance, so it could not be determined during compilation. The same as

```
*this
```

Comment: Ah that must be the problem. Well, balls. Oh well, I'll have to go with plan B. Thank you!